# Conditional formatting of x-axis label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I would like to bold x-axis label if the data associated is greater than 0. Seem easy but couldn't do it... Here my code :

```
options: {
    animation: false,
    scales: {
        x: {
            grid: {
                display: false
            },
            ticks: {
                callback: function (index) {
                    console.log('Index:', index);
                    console.log('Data:', data[index]);
                    console.log('Label:', labels[index]);
                    if (data[index] > 0) {
                        console.log("Data greater than 0")
                        return {
                            color: '#333',
                            font: {
                                weight: 'bold'
                            },
                            text: labels[index]
                        };
                    } else {
                        console.log("Data not greater than 0")
                        return {
                            color: '#333',
                            text: labels[index]
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

I add the `console.log` to help me debugging the thing, what the console return :

```
[Log] Index: – 0 (ascents.php, line 992)
[Log] Data: – 0 (ascents.php, line 993)
[Log] Label: – "Monday" (ascents.php, line 994)
[Log] Data not greater than 0 (ascents.php, line 1005)
[Log] Index: – 1 (ascents.php, line 992)
[Log] Data: – 0 (ascents.php, line 993)
[Log] Label: – "Tuesday" (ascents.php, line 994)
[Log] Data not greater than 0 (ascents.php, line 1005)
[Log] Index: – 2 (ascents.php, line 992)
[Log] Data: – "3" (ascents.php, line 993)
[Log] Label: – "Wednesday" (ascents.php, line 994)
[Log] Data greater than 0 (ascents.php, line 996)
[Log] Index: – 3 (ascents.php, line 992)
[Log] Data: – 0 (ascents.php, line 993)
[Log] Label: – "Thursday" (ascents.php, line 994)
[Log] Data not greater than 0 (ascents.php, line 1005)
[Log] Index: – 4 (ascents.php, line 992)
[Log] Data: – 0 (ascents.php, line 993)
[Log] Label: – "Friday" (ascents.php, line 994)
[Log] Data not greater than 0 (ascents.php, line 1005)
[Log] Index: – 5 (ascents.php, line 992)
[Log] Data: – 0 (ascents.php, line 993)
[Log] Label: – "Saturday" (ascents.php, line 994)
[Log] Data not greater than 0 (ascents.php, line 1005)
[Log] Index: – 6 (ascents.php, line 992)
[Log] Data: – 0 (ascents.php, line 993)
[Log] Label: – "Sunday" (ascents.php, line 994)
[Log] Data not greater than 0 (ascents.php, line 1005)
```

As you can see "Wednesday" should be bold but it's not as the picture below shows :

[What Safari displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfhNP.png)

Beyond formatting, even the days of the week no longer appear, but are replaced by "[object Object]".

Just for you to know, this display correctly the weekdays :

```
options: {
                animation: false,
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        grid: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        ticks: {
                            callback: function (index) {
                                if (data[index] > 0) {
                                    return labels[index];
                                } else {
                                    return labels[index];
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

But obviously there's not the conditional formatting I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Here the answer I found:

```
 x: {
    grid: {
        display: false
    },
    ticks: {
        font: {
            weight: function (context) {
                if (data[context.index] > 0) {
                    return 'bold';
                } else {
                    return 'normal';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```